# How to select (highlight and receive focus) entire text of selected cell in Delphi DBGrid?

Tags: delphi

I have a simple DBGrid, DBNavigator, and an 'Edit' Button which simply calls

```
DBNavigator.BtnClick(nbEdit);
```

When the user clicks 'Edit', I want the text in the selected cell (just the text - not the whole cell) to be highlighted - as if ready to be overwritten; whereas when I do

```
DBGid.SetFocus; 
DBNavigator.BtnClick(nbEdit);
```

the whole cell is highlighted.

How can I select the entire text of a selected cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set 'Options - dgAlwaysShowEditor' to true.

Comment: Yep, that achieves the objective. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please select my answer than (clicking the number in front of the anwswer). Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
DBGrid.SelectedField.FocusControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with me when I want to **highlight the field text** in grid to point to specific field when adding new item in grid.

```
grd->SelectedIndex = 1; // then field index
grd->EditMode = true;  
((TFloatField*)grd->SelectedIndex)->EditFormat = "";   // remove the format 
((TFloatField*)grd->SelectedIndex)->EditFormat = "#.00";   // set back editformat
grd->DataSource->DataSet->Edit();   // set dataset to edit mode
```

The trick is to change the `EditFormat`.